# Accessing service path parameters from CXF Message

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I am writing an interceptor to validate the requests that I see. However, I am unable to determine a way to access the path parameters (any parameter for that matter). Although, when I expand the message object in eclipse, debug console, I see what I want, but because it is an element in the array, I'm not sure which interface to use to access it.

What I see in eclipse (debugger):

[image]

My Interceptor :

```
public class ValidationInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>
{
    public ValidationInterceptor()
    {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    public void init() {}

    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault
    {
        OperationResourceInfo a = message.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
        Method methodMetaData = a.getMethodToInvoke();
        List<Parameter> metadataParameters =  a.getParameters();

        // ? How to access the parameters of the actual method invoked

        ...
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any help/pointers. Thank you.